# Is it relevant for CreateFile whether other handles to the same file have been opened by the same or a different process?

Tags: windows, winapi, createfile, windows-kernel

When working with filesystem files on Windows, and specifically with the [`CreateFile` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew):

With regard to access sharing, that is having multiple, independent, `CreateFile` calls to *open* the **same file**, possibly with different flags and sharing modes, does it matter in any way **whether file access is performed from within the same process or from a different process**?

That is, once someone has opened a file with `CreateFile(..., FILE_SHARE_READ, ...)`, noone should be able to open the same file with `GENERIC_WRITE` access. **Does it matter whether different calls originate from within the same process, or from different processes?**

My impression so far is that process boundaries do not matter for independent `CreateFile` calls to the same file. (They do matter for handle inheritance, etc.)

But that docs contain such gems as:

> To enable a **process** to share a file or device while **another process**
> has the file or device open, use a compatible combination of one or
> more of the following values. For more information about valid
> combinations of this parameter with the dwDesiredAccess parameter, see
> Creating and Opening Files.

which doesn't exactly inspire confidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In general such access restrictions to files don't care if they are done from the same or different process.

The file sharing flags work always the same way.

Answer (score 1):

As @xMRi answered, it does not matter if the Valid second call to CreateFile is in the same process or not.
[Creating and Opening Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/creating-and-opening-files)

> illustrates the valid combinations of two calls to CreateFile using
> various access modes and sharing modes (dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode
> respectively). It does not matter in which order the CreateFile calls
> are made.

An example to illustrate.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Tchar.h>
int main()
{
    //...
    HANDLE hFile1 = CreateFile(TEXT("tempfile"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        0,
        NULL);

    HANDLE hFile2 = CreateFile(TEXT("tempfile"),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ| FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (hFile1 != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && hFile2 != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        HANDLE hFile = hFile1;
        //HANDLE hFile = hFile2;
        FILE_BASIC_INFO fdi{};
        fdi.FileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;

        BOOL fResult = SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile,
            FileBasicInfo,
            &fdi,
            sizeof(FILE_BASIC_INFO));

        if (fResult)
        {
            // File will be deleted upon CloseHandle.
            _tprintf(TEXT("SetFileInformationByHandle marked tempfile for deletion\n"));

            // ... 
            // Now use the file for whatever temp data storage you need,
            // it will automatically be deleted upon CloseHandle or 
            // application termination.
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("error %lu:  SetFileInformationByHandle could not mark tempfile for deletion\n"),
                GetLastError());
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        // At this point, the file is closed and deleted by the system.
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("error %lu:  could not create tempfile\n"),
            GetLastError());
    }
    //...
}
```